# python and weierstrass function

Tags: c++, python-2.7

based on this [function](http://www.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/weierstrass/weier.htm). I'm trying to create two empty arrays (one for x and other for y), which later I will use to plot in python. But before anything this is what I have so far...

```
    import math

    x1=-2.0 
    x2=2.0

    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []

    i=0
    n=10
    delta=(x2-x1)/n
    for i in range (0,n+1):
        x=x1+delta*i        
        arr1.append(x)         
    print arr1
     # I have not called the w function yet
```

the code above creates a list of 10 numbers for now to keep it simple. Then it will send the elements of the array to the function below and compute the equation with certain numbers(infinite loop).

```
    #This function will create the array list for y
    import math

    def w(x, limit):# the limit here to compare when the number is really small            
        suma = 0.0
        sumb = 0.0
        m=1
        x=0
        suma=suma+((1/(math.pow(2,m))*(math.sin(math.pow(2,m)*x)))
        sumb=suma+((1/(math.pow(2,m+1))*(math.sin(math.pow(2,m+1)*x))) # I'm having a 
                                                                       #syntax error  
                                                                        #here
       x+=0
       if (abs (suma-sumb)<limit):
            break:
       else m+=1:
       if (m<20):
            break:
```

I will appreciate any help with my syntax errors or any suggestion. I just hope I was clear enough.
Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is actually on the previous line, where the parenthesis are not balanced. You need an extra `)` at the end of that line (and at the one you indicated as giving an error too btw).

There are also a few other issues

- `suma` is set to zero, so `suma = suma + ...` is the same as `suma = ...`, but I'm guessing you still need to add `while` loop before this line.
- On the line indicated, you have `sumb = suma +`, which is probably a copy/paste mistake.
- The code block starting at `x+=0` is indented by only 3 spaces instead of 4. This is probably not the case in your actual code, but if it is, Python will complain about that too.
- `else m+=1:` should be `else: m+=1` (colon directly after `else`, not at the end of the line.
- `break:` should just be `break` (without to colon).

Comment: ddk, thanks for or your comments. They really helped, and you were so right about the while loop...how do I pretend to create a loop without a for or while? duh for me! I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem! Glad to could have helped.